# Android AppWidget ListView won't populate

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider, android-appwidget-list

I’m having a hard time figuring out why my App Widget ListView won’t populate with data. Everything seems to be wired up right. When I debug, I can see the data that is being retrieved from my database (Firestore). However, it still won’t populate into the App Widget.

I created a new Issue on my Github to make it easier to view the problem:[Github Issue](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/issues/1)

#### [RemoteViewsFactory](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/acrutchfield/natashashairstudio/ui/ReviewsWidgetService.java)

- The data is successfully retrieved from `Firestore DB`
- `List<Review> reviews` is populated
- The `Review` objects within it contain the right data
- `get()` methods return the right data

#### [ReviewsAppWidgetProvider](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/acrutchfield/natashashairstudio/ui/ReviewsAppWidgetProvider.java)

- `ReviewsWidgetService Intent` is created
- `setRemoteAdapter()` is called using the `Intent` and passing in the `ListView` as well
- `updateAppWidget()` is called
- `notifyAppWIdgetViewDataChaged()` is called

#### [ReviewFragment](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/acrutchfield/natashashairstudio/ui/ReviewFragment.java)

- `ReviewsAppWidgetProvider.updateAppWidgets()` is called when adding or deleting reviews

#### [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

- `ReviewsAppWidgetProvider` declared as a reveiver
- Intent Filter set for `action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE`
- `ReviewsWidgetService` declared as Service
- permssion `BIND_REMOTEVIEWS` set

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.  **WOW** first question, you have really `gone to town` with this (Member for 1 year, 3 months) If only new users would do this. Well done !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, everything is ok with fetching data. But it's still draw a loading view. So the problem is in your [divider](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/39071039244ac8ff5330350a1d29b37a901f8307/app/src/main/res/layout/item_widget_review.xml#L65). View can't be used in app widgets, because launcher process doesn't know about view, it's only know about limited count of views, all views that can be used, you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

So how to make a such divider? 
Firstly you need a shape, so it will be something like *bottom_border.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#CCCCCC" />
</shape>
```

So now in your [root view](https://github.com/aaroncrutchfield/NatashasHairStudio/blob/39071039244ac8ff5330350a1d29b37a901f8307/app/src/main/res/layout/item_widget_review.xml#L2) add background *bottom_border.xml* like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
```